# form_tag not rendering in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am following the tutorial at http://www.noupe.com/ajax/create-a-simple-twitter-app.html
I am using ruby version 1.9.3p194 , rails version 3.2

When I created the view file index.html.erb , and put in the contents as

```
<b><%= render :partial => "message_form" %></b> 
<%= render :partial => @posts %>
```

and then in the form partial , _message_form.html.erb

```
 In partial _message_form
<% form_tag(:controller => "posts", :action => "create", :method=>"post") do %>  
  <%= label_tag(:message, "What are you doing?") %><br/>  
  <%= text_area_tag(:message, nil, :size => "44x6") %><br/>   
  <%= submit_tag("Update") %>  
<% end %>
```

and load the index.html.erb , I only see the message "In partial _message_form" . the form tags do not render at all.

Need help. Would be glad to provide any additional required information

Answer (score 12):

As far as I remember you need this: `<%= form_tag...`

**UPDATE**: There was a fallback to previous behavior (without `=`), but it doesn't seem to exist in Rails 3.2.6